# String and Text File Match Very basic

Tags: java

So i have recently dove head first into java trying to learn lots of things. Recently i have been studying File Writers and Reader and Buffered Writers and Readers. I have recently came to a haul though every time i turn on the application the text file is modified agian. Is there a way that my text file can update every time i change a string. So basically it will read the file on boot and compare it to the string.

Here is my example of reading a text file and turning it into a string

```
private void Read() {
    try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(version))) {
        String sCurrentLine;

        while((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(sCurrentLine);
        }
    } catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

All i need to do is it to compare this string with another. Thank you for your time.

** Update**

So i compared the two threads and now nothing is being written to the text file

```
private void Update() {
    try {
        fw= new FileWriter(version.getAbsoluteFile());
        bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);

    try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(version))) {
        String sCurrentLine;

        while((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            if(!sCurrentLine.equals(VanoEngine.TITLE)) {
                bw.write(VanoEngine.TITLE);
            }

        }

    } catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } 
    catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

** Update**

Closed the stream #JavaNoob and still nothing is being written

```
private void Update() {
    try {
        fw= new FileWriter(version.getAbsoluteFile());
        bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);

    try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(version))) {
        String sCurrentLine;

        while((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            if(!sCurrentLine.equals(VanoEngine.TITLE)) {
                bw.write(VanoEngine.TITLE);
            }

        }
        bw.close();
    } catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }

    } 
    catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: I could not understand your requirement,be more clear

Comment: Sorry first time on this website will try to be more clear in the future :)

Comment: if your question is clear then you will get more responses(answers or comments)

Comment: DO you want to perform file write or read operation? Which string you want to compare?

Comment: If someone could check the update to see what i did wrong in the comparing of the strings that would be great i think it is a little clearer now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(!sCurrentLine.equals(someInputString))
   //write `someInputString` to file, because it differs with the one read from file
```

Comment: So i compared the two thread can you look at what i did wrong now. Now it is not writing anything not sure what is going on

Comment: Don't forget to close the writing stream after you are done reading file. Do this after `while` loop: `bw.close()`.

Comment: Ok so i closed the writing stream and nothing is still happening

Comment: You cannot write data to file at the same time you read data from it at this manner. You should do like this:
    `if(!sCurrentLine.equals(VanoEngine.TITLE)) {
       br.close();
       bw.write(VanoEngine.TITLE);
    }`

Answer (score 0):

you can use sCurrentLine.equals("your string").